# How to access a wallet in bitcoin core using raw key export from edge wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mnemonic-seed, private-key-import

I have a wallet in the Edge Wallet app. When I view "Raw Keys", I see this json:

```
{
"format": "bip49 ",
"bitcoinKey": <seed phrase>,
"coinType": 0,
"dataKey": <dataKey gobbledygook>,
"syncKey": <syncKey gobbledygook>
}
```

How do I use this information to access/reconstruct this wallet in bitcoin core?
A set of exact steps to follow would be nice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a BIP39 12-word mnemonic be used to restore a wallet through bitcoin-cli?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/87407/can-a-bip39-12-word-mnemonic-be-used-to-restore-a-wallet-through-bitcoin-cli)

Comment: No, not at all. I am not trying to enter a seed phrase into bitcoin core. I'm trying to extract the private key from the given data so that I can import that private key into bitcoin core.

Comment: @steven but you mentioned "seed phrase", so we could have guessed you meant "mnemonic". Does this `bitcoinKey` field outputs a raw key, an xpub, or mnemonics ? Depending on this i can write an answer..

Comment: @darosior the "bitcoinKey" is a 24 word mnemonic seed phrase as you'd expect. If you install Edge wallet, make a bitcoin wallet, then go to View Raw Keys, you'll see output just like what I posted. I'm wanting to use this raw key info to access funds in bitcoin core.